# How do I retrieve attributes programmatically using jquery in order to optimize my event handlers?

Tags: jquery, attributes, event-handling, label, radiobuttonlist

I'm using the .on() method to show/hide content depending on which label has been clicked; and to indicate which radio is currently checked.

I want my code to programmatic, so that the data-type of the label and the value of the input are dynamic rather than hard coded.

What's the best approach?

```
$('.js-choice[data-type="skip"]').on('click', function () {
  $('input[name="choice"][value="1"]').prop('checked', true);
  $(jsSkip).removeClass('hide-content');
  $(jsAddr).addClass('hide-content');
  $(jsNew).addClass('hide-content');
});
```

Here is a link to my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/curlybraces/x8Qbz/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle, you are using a lot of classes but no ids. Start by giving an `id` similar to the `data-type` attribute of your labels to the three `<div>`s. Also add a class to the `div`s that identifies them as a container for your form fields. They have that in common.

In your JavaScript, all you need to do now is select the `<label>`s, which have the class `js-choice`. To each of them you apply an `onClick` handler. That handler just needs to hide all of the `<div>`s that have form fields and show the one belonging to the `<label>` that was clicked.

This leaves us with this simple function:

```
$('.js-choice').each(function () {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        $('.form-fields').addClass('hide-content');
        $('#fields-' + $(this).attr('data-type')).removeClass('hide-content');
    });
});
```

I've [updated your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8Qbz/3/).